# Extract data from returned string

Tags: java, groovy, katalon-studio

I'm using Katalon Studio and using it to send an API request. The request is basically returning information I want to use in the HTTP Header. I can use Groovy or Java to extract this but not sure how I can do it.

I've tried `create_game_response.getHeadewrFields(GameCode)` in order to get the GameCode but it won't work.

Here is the code I use

```
WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('UserRestService/Create Game'))
WS.verifyResponseStatusCode(create_game_response, 201)

def header_text = create_game_response.getHeaderFields()
println(header_text)

def game_code = create_game_response.getHeaderFields();

String game_code_list = game_code.toString()

println(game_code_list)
```

And this is the response:

```
{GameCode=[1jwoz2qy0js], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], null=[HTTP/1.1 201 Created]}
```

I'm trying to extract "1jwoz2qy0js" from the game code and use it as a string, how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`getHeaderFields()`](https://api-docs.katalon.com/com/kms/katalon/core/testobject/ResponseObject.html#getHeaderFields()) returns a Map of the headers where each header is a List. Rather than converting that to a String and attempting to parse it, just get the field you want:

```
Map headers = create_game_response.getHeaderFields()

List gameCodes = headers["GameCode"]
```

And then select the first one, if that's all there is:

```
assert gamesCodes[0] == "1jwoz2qy0js"
```

Answer (score 0):

Groovy code below:
​

```
str = '{GameCode=[1jwoz2qy0js], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], null=[HTTP/1.1 201 Created]}'​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
left_idx = str.indexOf('[') + 1
right_idx = str.indexOf(']')
print str.substring(left_idx,right_idx)
```

Output:

```
1jwoz2qy0js
```